# Does 40/100, SD/30 d10 mean that the delay is applied to both time controls?

Tags: tournament, time-control

I am going to be going to my first tournament soon (the southern class championship),  and am slightly confused about the time control.  Most tournament listings have something along the lines of 40/100, SD/30, d10 which makes it obvious that the 10 second delay applies to both time controls.   However, the listing for the tournament says 40/100, SD/30 d10.  The lack of comma makes me think that possibly this delay only applies to the second time control.  Is this something I should ask the director about, or is this just another way to write a delay that applies to both time controls?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the tournament is run by the Continental Chess Association. From my experience playing in many CCA tournaments, the d10 is applied to both time controls.

Comment: You are right, as can be seen in the [Continental Chess Association Rules](http://www.chesstour.com/rules.htm): "3. [...] Time delay clocks should be set for the specified delay for entire game".

Answer (score 1):

The standard setting is for the delay to be applied to both time controls. I haven't heard of a tournament that has only applied the delay to one of the time controls. So it should be safe to assume the delay is enduring throughout the whole game, but it never hurts to ask the TD just in case.